# Unable to run test suite(multiple test scripts) in Casperjs

Tags: casperjs

Hi I have got a problem with running multiple test .js in CasperJS.

I want runing multiple files test .js

I execute this command in console:

casperjs /var/www/run.js /var/www/casper/tests

And see this error:

CasperError: casper.test property is only available using the `casperjs test` command

And no use the property 'test' in any test.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute a **test** suite, you have to use the casperjs **test** command.

```
casperjs test /var/www/casper/tests
```

Or go in the repertory containing your tests folder, and execute one of these commands :

```
casperjs test tests
casperjs test tests/
casperjs test ./tests
```

http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html

And if you want to include some files : use --includes

https://gist.github.com/n1k0/2948039

or phantom.injectJs(path/to/your/jsFile.js)